# How to pass assembly reference to Razor.Parse()

Tags: razor, .net-assembly

I am using the RazerEngine at https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

I am wondering how and if it is possible to pass an assembly reference to the engine?

Say I have some logic in an external DLL - how can I call a method in a custom DLL?

```
string template = "@using ClassLibrary1 @ClassLibrary1.Class1.SomethingFromADLL()   ";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, m);
```

This results in an exception

**Unable to compile template. The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 0):

you have to find your necessary method and just write its name. For example:

String.Trim();

and 
string template="String.Trim()";

Comment: But String.Trim() is a base class library function that will already be included in the razor parser. I am talking about a custom DLL that I write with a static method in it. I need to somehow add its assembly to a list of assemblies that the razor engine is going to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I add the following line prior to the Razor.Parse method it now has access to the ClassLibrary1

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("ClassLibrary1");

string template = "@using ClassLibrary1 @ClassLibrary1.Class1.SomethingFromADLL()   ";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, m);
```